# Modify how mongodb 3.4 starts on centos 7

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, centos7

I'm trying to start a mongodb 3.4 on a EC2 Centos 7.3 machine.

The problem is that the default startup script installed by the rpm, throws this error:

```
2017-07-26T13:01:29.820-0400 I NETWORK  [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
2017-07-26T13:01:29.822-0400 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/local/mongo-data/diagnostic.data'
2017-07-26T13:01:29.822-0400 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup.
2017-07-26T13:01:29.822-0400 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset
2017-07-26T13:01:29.823-0400 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2017-07-26T13:01:29.823-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-07-26T13:01:29.823-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
2017-07-26T13:01:29.823-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2017-07-26T13:01:29.823-0400 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-07-26T13:01:29.823-0400 I REPL     [signalProcessingThread] shutting down replication subsystems
2017-07-26T13:01:29.824-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-07-26T13:01:29.824-0400 I FTDC     [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture
2017-07-26T13:01:29.824-0400 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2017-07-26T13:01:29.894-0400 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-07-26T13:01:29.894-0400 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2017-07-26T13:01:29.894-0400 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0
```

As I cannot find anything that is helpful related to that `[initandlisten] Did not find local voted for document at startup.` or `[initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup;  NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset`.

I succeeded starting mongo with

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

And it works. No issues. The above command I guess that is the same as the init script started with `systemctl start mongod`

My config file looks like this:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongo/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /local/mongo-data
  journal:
    enabled: true

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongo.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  http:
    RESTInterfaceEnabled: true

replication:
  replSetName: res0
```

Now... maybe someone can enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong and why the default startup script does not work. 
But the question is how can I replace the default startup script with my workaround... `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Thank you,
Gabriel

Comment: You have not initialized your replica set **`res0`**.

Comment: i did not. It is done automatically from chef, but in order for that to happen, the mongo should start and open 27017 port on localhost

Comment: Well, obviously something went wrong. I really suggest doing it manually first (a couple of times) before using chef recipes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that with chef I was changing from the template the default data folder and log folder and the selinux was denying access to them. Adjusting the selinux to permissive for mongod user solved the problem.

Thank you all for your answers.